# Flutter Disable and Enable Button based on the user input on textfield

Tags: flutter, button, textfield

How can I disable a button when the user hasn't added any content to the textfield yet and then enable it once the user type something?

Is it possible? And if no is there another way to do it?

Thanks

```
return AlertDialog(
      
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
      content: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 20.0),
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a new message...'),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _newMessage = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          color: Colors.tealAccent,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.navigate_next_rounded,
            size: 40.0,
          ),
          onPressed: _newMessage.trim().isEmpty ? null :  _sendNewMessage,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achive this you have to get the lenght of the input from the textfield, the correct way is to use a [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) but for this simple purpose a workarount should do the job.

Code:

Initialize a new bool isInputEmpty before the `return AlertDialog`

```dart
    onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _newMessage = value;

                  if(_newMessage.length > 0){  //add these lines
                     isInputEmpty = false;
                  } else {
                     isInputEmpty = true;
                  }

                });
              },
```

and to disable to button you can wrap him inside a [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)

```dart
IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: isInputEmpty,
          child: IconButton(...),
),
```

You can even change the button color:

```dart
IconButton(
          color: isInputEmpty ? Colors.grey : Colors.tealAccent,
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Text Editing Controller https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

```
final controller = TextEditingController();
 onPressed: controller.text.length==0 ? null :  _sendNewMessage,
```

pls check if the .length is correct can't remember haha

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the first answer but I still tried yours and it's also worked